# How to test Mongoose Schema Decorator in NestJs

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I need to test Schema Decorator via jest

[image]

Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

Move the method to a dedicated function variable that can be called externally of the decorator, then call that variable in the test directly. Or e2e tests